# How to properly randomize data with seed.rb using Factory Girl and random_data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, factory-bot, factories

I gave generating test data a first shot by trying to populate my database with a simple script that creates a sufficient number of records for my models accounting for all dependencies (esp. polymorphism).

This is my `seeds.rb`

```
require 'factory_girl_rails'

50.times do

  @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
  FactoryGirl.create(:contact, :user => @user)

  @question = FactoryGirl.create(:question, :user => @user)

  FactoryGirl.create(:user_answer, :question => @question, :authorable => @user)

  @contact = FactoryGirl.create(:contact, :user => @user)
  FactoryGirl.create(:contact_answer, :question => @question, :authorable => @contact)

end
```

As an example, here ist the `question` factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :question do
    title       "What is the best place to travel in " + Random.country + "?"
    body        Random.paragraphs(2)
    association :user, :method => :build
  end
end
```

While the `Random` class does produce *one* random term, that term remains the same for all instances created. In this case I would get 50 questions of, say, "What is the best place to travel in Spain?" and the identical two paragraphs of text for each.

What am I missing?

Comment: `seeds.rb` should only be used to add required 'static' data to the database, not to 'fixture' it. To create base data so you can manually test the application on development, you should create a rake task (we have `rake db:populate`)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Would you expect the behavior to change, though, if I were to run the same in a separate task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I'm not sure where the `Random` class is coming from here. But I always used the [Faker gem](http://faker.rubyforge.org/rdoc/) for this stuff.

It does names, emails, cities, phone numbers: like this:

```
Faker::Name.name
Faker::Address.uk_country
Faker::Lorem.paragraph
```

check it out

Comment: FYI @Matthew: [This is where the Random class comes from](https://github.com/tomharris/random_data).